# how to change the date format in every first element of a sublist

Tags: python, function, datetime, nested-lists

I have a nested list like this: datelist = [["2019/04/12", 7.0], ["2019/02/09", 7.3], ["2018/08/14", 6.1]]
I need to change the date format from yyyy/mm/dd/ to yyyy.mm.dd and then return the list as it is.
So the result should be [["12.04.2019", 7.0], ["09.02.2019", 7.3], ["14.08.2018", 6.1]].

I'm a beginner, so I'm really not sure how to do it.

I tried the following:

```
import datetime
datelist = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i[0]), "%Y/%m/%d").strftime('%d.%m.%Y') for i in datelist]
print(datelist)
```

and the output was:

['12.04.2019', '09.02.2019', '14.08.2016']

So the change of the data format worked, but how do I return the the original nested list with the corrected data format?

I need to implement this as a function which takes lists like datelist as an input.

Comment: `[[datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%d").strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), value] for date, value in datelist]`

Comment: You can do this through looping. Use the same method as above but do it in iterations. You can then get the original list in the format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your script like below:

```py
datelist = [[datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i[0]), "%Y/%m/%d").strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), i[1]] for i in datelist]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
datelist = [[datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i[0]), "%Y/%m/%d").strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), i[1]] for i in mylist]
```

When iterating throughout your list, you get back a list, knowing the position of your elements in the list helps, thus using i[0] for the first element (datetime), and i[1] for the second (number).